# Удалить неполную строку в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть вот такой запрос
Нужно вывести только те строки где property_values имеет все три значения

```
SELECT
title,
stock,
price,
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.title, ': ', pv.value SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM ( SELECT * FROM product_property_value pv WHERE (pv.property_id,pv.value)=(1,"Красный" ) or (pv.property_id,pv.value)=(2,4 ) or (pv.property_id,pv.value)=(2,5 ) or (pv.property_id,pv.value)=(3,5 )) pv
  
    INNER JOIN property p on pv.property_id = p.id WHERE pv.product_id = product.id
) property_values
```

FROM product ORDER BY property_values;

И в картинке результат. КАК мне вывести только те строки где в property_values есть все три значения?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: рядом с GROUP_CONCAT выведите count(*) и обратите внимание что он равен 3 для нужных строк ...

Comment: Не получается, выдаёт ошибку